# Python - sys.argv special symbol (€, ¢, ₪, etc…)

Tags: python, input, unicode, parameters

I have to work with currency symbols on input parameters of my python file. Well, but I don't know, how to convert it to useable way.

Example:

My input:

```
--amount 100.0 --input_currency € --output_currency CZK
```

What I get for the € symbol:

```
\x80
```

What I need to get:

```
u'\u20ac'
```

I tried to use decode('utf-8') but it doesn't work, it returns:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

Can you help me please?

Comment: What operating system you're using affects how parameters to you program are encoded. What OS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On POSIX systems, it depends entirely on how your console or terminal is configured what encoding is used for those strings.

In those environments, use [`locale.getpreferredencoding()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/locale.html#locale.getpreferredencoding) to query what encoding was configured, then use that to decode the string. This is *not foolproof*, but should work whenever the console or terminal was configured correctly.

In your specific case you probably are using a Windows system configured to use [Windows Codepage 1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252):

```
>>> '\x80'.decode('cp1252')
u'\u20ac'
>>> print '\x80'.decode('cp1252')
€
```

Windows does provide the [`GetCommandLineW()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683156(v=vs.85).aspx) and [`CommandLineToArgvW()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776391(v=vs.85).aspx) functions to retrieve the *Unicode* value for the command line, and then parse that value into an `argv`-like array; using this from Python can be done with the [`ctypes` library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html); paraphrasing [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/878972/windows-cmd-encoding-change-causes-python-crash/3259271#3259271) this is how you could use it:

```
from ctypes import WINFUNCTYPE, windll, POINTER, byref, c_int
from ctypes.wintypes import LPWSTR, LPCWSTR
GetCommandLineW = WINFUNCTYPE(LPWSTR)(("GetCommandLineW", windll.kernel32))
CommandLineToArgvW = WINFUNCTYPE(POINTER(LPWSTR), LPCWSTR, POINTER(c_int))(("CommandLineToArgvW", windll.shell32))

argc = c_int(0)
argv_unicode = CommandLineToArgvW(GetCommandLineW(), byref(argc))
```

Comment: ...and because you're using code page 1252, you won't be able to use `₪`, as this character doesn't exist in that code page. The Windows Console is not a good place to be doing anything to do with Unicode.

Answer (score 0):

On Python 3, `sys.argv` is already a list of Unicode strings. You don't need to do anything.

On Python 2, on Windows, you should [use Unicode API (`CommandLineToArgvW()`, `GetCommandLineW()`)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3259271/4279). It allows to pass characters that can't be represented using the current OEM code page such as cp437 (`chcp` result).

On Python 2, on POSIX, `sys.argv[i]` may be an arbitrary byte sequence. Normally, It may be encoded using `sys.getfilesystemencoding()` that is derived from locale on Linux.

See [Best way to decode command line inputs to Unicode Python 2.7 scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33841721/4279).

Comment: Then Linux appears to act differently from my Mac OS X terminal, where it is the *locale* that determines how command-line arguments are encoded. It is the locale that determines how my terminal input is encoded and thus how Bash receives it, at any rate.